# Using Discord.py rewrite to delete messages

Tags: discord, discord.py

As the title states, I'm trying to delete messages using my !purge command. I have this down already:

```
    @bot.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def purge(ctx):
        await delete_messages(ctx, member)
        await ctx.send("Deleted messages")
```

It's saying that `delete_messages` is not defined. Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

So we are in year 2019. I'll help you with your code.

`delete_messages` is a method of a TextChannel object.

In your line `await delete_messages(ctx, member)`, add `ctx.message.channel.` just before delete_messages.

Your line would then go like this:
`await ctx.message.channel.delete_messages(ctx, member)`

Hope that clears things up.
If it did, don't hesitate to 'accept' the answer by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

This will delete only up to 99 messages (+ the purge command) at a time and the messages must be under 14 days old.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, name='purge', aliases=['purgemessages'], no_pm=True)
async def purge(ctx, number):
    number = int(number)
        if number > 99 or number < 1:
            await ctx.send("I can only delete messages within a range of 1 - 99", delete_after=10)
        else:
            author = ctx.message.author
                authorID = author.id
                mgs = []
                number = int(number)
                channel = ctx.message.channel
                async for x in bot.logs_from((channel), limit = int(number+1)):
                    mgs.append(x)
                await delete_messages(mgs)
                await ctx.send('Success!', delete_after=4)
```